# recyclerview animation not working with objectanimator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, material-design, objectanimator

`enter code here`I want to implement a animation for items in a `Recyclerview` using `ObjectAnimator`. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8ifO1m9g_Q)

Here is my code for getting animations:

```
public static void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean direction)
{
    AnimatorSet animatorSet=new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator animator_Y=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"TranslationY",direction==true ? 100 : -100,0);
    animator_Y.setDuration(1000);

    ObjectAnimator animator_X=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"TranslationX",-20,20,0);
    animator_X.setDuration(1000);

    animatorSet.playTogether(animator_X,animator_Y);
    animatorSet.start();
    Log.e("animation","animation running");
}
```

I am calling this function from `onBindViewHolder()`. There is no animation from translationX and translationY. And I am sure that this method is being called everytime I scroll.

I want know that `ObjectAnimator` is used for `Cardview` or not. Thank you.`

This is my onBindViewHolder Method

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.textView.setText(data.get(position));
    AnimationforAdapters.animate(holder,true);
}
```

Comment: Try by replacing `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` with `translationX`  and `translationY` respectively

Comment: I have changed to  translationX and translationY, but no animation occurs.Thanks harry for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public static void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean direction) {
    AnimatorSet animatorSet=new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator animator_Y=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"translationY",direction ? 100 : -100,0);
    animator_Y.setDuration(1000);

    ObjectAnimator animator_X=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView,"translationX",-20,20,0);
    animator_X.setDuration(1000);

    animatorSet.playTogether(animator_X,animator_Y);
    animatorSet.start();
    Log.e("animation","animation running");
}
```

As mentioned in the android documentation for [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

> This subclass of ValueAnimator provides support for animating properties on target objects. The constructors of this class take parameters to define the target object that will be animated as well as the name of the property that will be animated. Appropriate set/get functions are then determined internally and the animation will call these functions as necessary to animate the property.

So, the problem in your code was that the `ObjectAnimator` could not find properties `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` in your target object that can be animated.

Comment: I have tried translationX and translationY, no change in listview of cards.  Is there any limit for no.of cards in the recyclerview ??

Comment: Nope there is no such limit

Answer (score 0):

use this its work for me :

```
public void slideAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean animate) {
    ObjectAnimator animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", animate ? 40 : -40, 1f);
    ObjectAnimator animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationX", animate ? 40 : -40, 1f);
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(animatorX , animatorY);
    set.setDuration(1000);
    set.start();

}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, its not working.Which  itemview are u using inside the recyclerview and is there any min limit for  no.of items inside recyclerview

Comment: I have added the  onBindViewHolder() method in my post

Answer (score 0):

try by maintaining reference of your row layout parent root xml tag into holder and use that instead of using holder.itemview.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I have not enabled the animations in my device.Make Window animation scale,Transition animation scale,Animator duration scale to 1x inside the developer options.